# capistrano deploy_via :copy using git tags?

Tags: ruby, git, capistrano

I'm new to capistrano and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to deploy to multiple servers by using a push method with git tags as a reference. It's a little more complicated than that, as these are Windows servers with FreeSSH installed. I have this so far:

deploy.rb:

```
set :application, "iis_app"
set :repo_url, "iis_repo"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_cache, true
```

server definitions:

```
role :push_servers, %w{"srv1" "srv2" "srv3" "srv4"} 

ssh_options: {
  user: "windows_user",
  forward_agent: true,
  auth_methods: %w(password),
  password: ENV["WINDOWS_PW"]
}
```

Otherwise I'm a bit lost. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your config looks fine. The only thing is that your `:repo_url` should be something like this:

```
git@github.com:mycompany/myrepo.git
```

A git tag is essentially translates to a revision (SHA1 hash) so you can just do something like this:

**For Capistrano 2.9 and above:**

```
cap -S revision=<the sha1 of your tag> deploy
```

**For older versions of Capistrano**, you can do this:

```
cap -s branch=<the sha1 of your tag> deploy
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using capistrano 3.2.1. There doesn't seem to be a -S option. I didn't see one in the help output. I get this when I try the command you suggested: cap -S revision='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' deploy production
invalid option: -S

Comment: Seems the lowercase -s works though. I get something. Not quite what I thought though. It seems to want to create the cache on each of the servers.  INFO[553761a5] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/tier1_secure/ on "srv1"
DEBUG[553761a5] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/iis_app/

Comment: I was hoping to get something that would create the cache locally and then push it over to the servers, like scp or rsync would. I'm trying to interact with the Windows servers as little as possible since the FreeSSH software does not provide a shell.